# How do i prevent Xcode from overwriting iTunes binary?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a really annoying problem. My app is published in the AppStore.

Everytime i run the app from Xcode, the iTunes binary just gets overwritten... and next time i need to test something with the production version of the app, i need to re-download it.

Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried changing the bundle identifier?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change your bundle identifier. Here's how I set it up in my projects

- Select your Project
- Select your target
- Navigate to the `Info` tab
- Change the `bundle identifier` to a custom build setting e.g. I have it as `${BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER}`

[image]

- Now click on `Project` - (you may wish to keep at target level your choice)
- Navigate to the `Build Settings` tab
- Scroll all the way to the bottom to see `User-Defined`
- Click `Add Build Setting`

  - (1) Select `Add User-Defined Setting`
- (2) Add `Key` as the name you chose earlier
- Set a different bundle identifier for each scheme

[image]

---

### Bonus

You can use the same trick for icons so you can easily tell apart your builds on one device

Answer (score 1):

Changing the bundle identifier, as Paul.s suggested, works — but it means your Release and Debug builds will diverge. Technically they will be different apps that use different containers. There can be good reasons to do this, but it has it's risks too: it's a bit more complicated, and you usually have to work a little harder to make sure you test that the development version [properly handles data from the production version](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2285/_index.html). You'll want to make sure any ad hoc builds you send to testers use the production bundle identifier.

Another way to approach the problem is to streamline installing the old version. If you [Archive](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/DistApps/DistApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH11-SW2) your production builds, then you can install them without downloading them again through the App Store. Just open-up a previously exported IPA and sync.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow when you say using different identifiers is risky? What makes it more complicated? And why is it any more work? Installing over a release build is a poor experience for the customer who may be using the product they are paying for, whilst you are continuing development. Using a different identifier for ad hoc gives the chance to properly test the upgrade path in a safer environment, without potentially ruining a users live data. The article you linked to suggests not to debug release issues with Xcode, it says archiving is fine - which is what ad hocs are for

Comment: Paul.s, using a different bundle identifier in your ad hoc builds does *not* properly test the upgrade path, because all data (including caches) created by the earlier version of the app won't be copied over into the ad hoc build's container. The best way to test an upgrade is to install a new build over an existing build (meaning both apps must have the same bundle identifier). I have seen catastrophic bugs get missed because extensive testing was only done with "side" builds that didn't pickup pre-existing data.

Comment: Paul.s, you are right that "Installing over a release build is a poor experience for the customer". But that needs to be balanced with fully testing what will happen when existing customers update. Like I said, I've seen some pretty bad bugs get missed because the update path wasn't fully tested. So I recommend overwriting. But your projects are different than mine! Obviously you know what works for your situation better than I do :-).

Comment: @VincentGable yup sorry I forgot dev isn't a one size fits all thing. :)